# ¿Como puedo referenciar un segmento de Firebase Storage desde Android?

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas comunidad, tengo un problema, y es que no sé como referenciar un segemento determinado de Firebase Storage desde el código Android para guardar, cargar o borrar una imagen, me refiero al segmento que no está como predeterminado. Gracias y un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cuando creas la referencia al storage en el `getInstance().getReference()` puedes usar el `getReferenceFromUrl("");` y dentro de las comillas pasar la url de firebase

por ejemplo esto encuentras [Aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/create-reference?hl=es-419) en la documentación de firebase

// Create a storage reference from our storage service

```
Firebase.Storage.StorageReference storage_ref =
  storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>");
```

recuerda que si vas a Storage en Firebase, puedes encontrar el link arriba

[image: Aqui un ejemplo]

Espero te sirva